# json encode in magento 2

Tags: magento2, json

I just wanted to know that what is the right way to print array data into json format. I Know we can use php function `json_encode()` but is this the right way to print array data? Because i saw one of magento's core file, there was something like this

```
        if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
            $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class
                )->jsonEncode(
                    ['error' => true, 'message' => $_keyErrorMsg]
                )
            );
        } else {
            $this->_redirect($this->_backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl());
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so if we look at this section

```
$this->getResponse()->representJson(
                $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class
                )->jsonEncode(
                    ['error' => true, 'message' => $_keyErrorMsg]
                )
            );
```

we see magento is encoding data using `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` class.

I am working on custom APIs where i need to send data in json format. So please correct me if i am not wrong that we can also print Array data using this `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` class.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays, the recommended dependency to inject would be the `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface`.

Comment: Care to elaborate? The serializer provided here seems to use PHP's serialize function, which does not return JSON data. The OP was asking specifically how to serialize data into the JSON format.

Comment: Actually, `Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface` has had a DI preference for `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` for many years now. Even better, the suggested class `Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` is deprecated since Magento 2.1 (?) and its suggested replacement is `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` (which is preferenced through with the mentioned interface). See the Magento core code for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, must've overlooked that!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` using object manager you can use like this

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $jsonHelper;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
{
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}

/**
 * @param array $dataToEncode
 * @return string
 */
public function encodeSomething(array $dataToEncode)
{
    if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
    if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode(
                ['error' => true, 'message' => $_keyErrorMsg]
        );
    } else {
        $this->_redirect($this->_backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl());
    }
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}
    }

You can see This [Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242402/unable-to-get-jsonencode-in-magento2)

Comment: the question is not about using object manager.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: @sudo55 Your question was not about using the Object Manager, but how to properly handle JSON data. If you worry about properly doing things in Magento 2, then using the Object Manager properly is actually more important than handling JSON data properly :) Just my 50 cents

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to use the old json helper \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data, i.e. you are implementing \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity that has:

```
protected $jsonHelper;
```

built with the old helper by constructor, you still can overwrite the constructor of the abstract class in yours, and use a custom class to override $jsonHelper, like this one:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class JsonSerializer extends Json
{
    /**
     * Serialize data into string
     *
     * @param mixed $data
     * @return string|bool
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function jsonEncode($data)
    {
        return $this->serialize($data);
    }

    /**
     * Unserialize the given string
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @return mixed
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function jsonDecode(string $string)
    {
        return $this->unserialize($string);
    }
}
```